# Slowmode command always sends the same thing

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get my slowmode command working. Basically when I type >sm 2s it replies with "Please follow this example: ;sm 5" <-- this reply should just send if args are null.

````
  if(args[1] == null) { 
       return message.channel.send("Please follow this example: ;sm 5")
   }if (args[1] !== null) {
    message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(args[0])
    message.channel.send(`Slowmode is now ${args[0]}s`)
}}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "sm",
    aliases: []
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript and most other languages, you could refer to `!` in functions as `not`.

For example, let's take `message.member.hasPermission()`. If we add `!` at the start, giving us:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') return
```

We're basically telling the client, `if the message member does **not** have the administrator permission, return the command`.

Now, let's take your if statement, saying `if (!args[1] == null) {`, you're basically telling the client `if not args[1] equals to null do this:`, which let's face it makes totally no sense.

When we want to compare a variable with a certain value, we would want to tell the client `if args[1] is **not** equal to null, do this.` Hence why you should fix you if statement into saying:

```
if (args[1] !== null) {
```

Sorry for the pretty long answer, felt like giving a little lesson to someone :p

Comment: sadly still responds only with that I mentioned earlier.. [https://imgur.com/a/Cj72xza]

Comment: Here's what I'd suggest:
Instead of checking if args[1] is null, I'd suggest simply doing:
`if (!args[1]) return // would return if no input of args[1] was given.`
`message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(args[0])`

This code seems to be working just fine!

Comment: Ehhh, I mean I need it so when args is null my bot will just return, Not when there's args.